# Cannot find the element on the web using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I need your help, please. I am using selenium to click a button on a web page, which then opens other options. Unfortunately it does not recognize the Path element. The web simulator is in mobile version as it is easier to access the buttons (the problem is the same for desktop version). I tried to click on other buttons on the web page and it worked correctly.

```
mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "Galaxy S5" }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, options=chrome_options) 
driver.get('https://www...')

time.sleep(20)

Click1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header_3"]/div')
Click1.click()
```

The error is:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="header_3"]/div"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)
```

The image of the web code is as follows:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the imports in order to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//div[contains(@id, 'header_3')]//div
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'header_3')]//div").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id, 'header_3')]//div"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'header_3')]//div")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'header_3')]//div")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted**.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Click1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="card-header"]')
```

or

```
Click1 = driver.find_element_by_id("header_3")
```